# multiple tables in my sqli

Tags: php, mysql

first i want to sorry for my bad english :D
second , i have a project in my college in sql and php that the doctor asked me to make 4 tables ( clients , payment , project , flats )
clients table have a relation with payment table and project table with a foreign key , and project table have a relation with flats table 
i can make an insert statment to show all information on clients,payment and project tables

```
( SELECT clients.name, payment.first_cash, project_type.type_of_flat
FROM clients
INNER JOIN payment ON clients.client_id = payment.client_id
INNER JOIN project_type ON clients.client_id = project_type.client_id

LIMIT 0 , 30 )
```

now i want to show information in flat table also ,,

project table has a relation with flats table
project table is the parent and flats table is the child

thanks in advance and sorry again for my bad english :D
__

why the row repeated now ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytgFo.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add another JOIN with flats table.

```
SELECT clients.name, payment.first_cash, project_type.type_of_flat
FROM clients
INNER JOIN payment ON clients.client_id = payment.client_id
INNER JOIN project_type ON clients.client_id = project_type.client_id
INNER JOIN flats ON flats.project_id = project_type.project_id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

In JOINS, you join two tables with an `id` field.

First table has actual data and the `id` field generally is its `Primary Key`.

Second table has reference with first table's `id` field which is `Foreign Key`.

Comment: thank you guy ,, now i added a new problem in the topic :D